# Value not display in ejs page

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to display the database value in an ejs page but it is not showing. My schema is not added to the database and not showing value to the ejs page

model.js

```
const addedSchema = new Schema({
    AddedName: {
        type:String
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: String, 
        default: () => moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
    },
    addedBy: {
          type: String
       }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('added', addedSchema);
```

added.ejs

```
 <% for(var i = 0; i <added. length; i++) { %>  
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><%= i+1 %></td>
                                            <td><%= added[i].AddedName %></td>
                                            <td><%= added[i].timestamp %></td>
                                            <td><%= added[i].addedBy %></td>
                                            <td>    

                                                    <div class="justify-content-md-center" style="width:250px !important">
                                                        <a href="/viewed/<%= added[i]._id %>" class="btn bg-blue-w rounded">view</a>
                                                        <a href="/deleting/<%= added[i]._id %>" class="btn bg-grey rounded">Delete</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <%  } %>
```

addedcontroller.js
//added user

```
const Data = new Added( {AddedName: 'abc',
addedBy: 'uhd'})
Data.save()
   .then(doc => {
     console.log(doc)
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.error(err)
   })
router.get('/added', async (req,res) => {
    const added = await Added . find();
    res.render('added' , {
        added
    });

});
```

It is not inserted into the database and showing Value. Please, any help?

Getting page
[image]

value of database not showing. In the command prompt, it shows
[image]

No database schema is creating name added

Comment: it would be great if you share errors that are coming ? please go through step by step first make sure collection is been created on mongo then verify your request

Comment: Added the image I am getting